# how to get just the real part of complex no. in haskell or its imaginary part?

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Complex
realPart :: (RealFloat a) => Complex a -> a
realPart (x :+ _) =  x
imagPart :: (RealFloat a) => Complex a -> a
imagPart (_ :+ x) =  x
```

this is the code I have but when I execute `realPart 2:+3` it gives 2.0 :+ 3.0 as output where I just need 2 as output. Is there any way out there to get it?
also when I execute `imagPart 2:+3` it gives  0.0 :+ 3.0
as output where I need 3 only.

Comment: Those two functions are already define in `Data.Complex`.

Answer (score 11):

Function application binds more tightly than any infix, including `:+`. Therefore, what you have is parsed as `(realPart 2) :+ 3`, which is simply `2 :+ 3` (in `realPart 2`, the `2` is interpreted as a complex `Num` literal, i.e. as `2 :+ 0`).

To prevent this, use either parens or `$` for manual grouping: `realPart $ 2 :+ 3` will give 2.

Answer (score 6):

Putting parenthesis should solve:

```
ghci> realPart (2:+3)
2.0

ghci> imagPart (2:+3)
3.0
```

When you don't put parenthesis, it behaves like this:

```
ghci> (realPart 2) :+ 3
2.0 :+ 3.0
```